# Set android application expire date from installation date

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to set my application work for 10 days from the installation date.For that I go-through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819383/how-to-make-an-application-work-for-only-3-days) Other than the calendar function any other method to check for expire date?.thanks in advance.

Comment: Why cant you make use of `Calendar`?? Why do u need `Other than the Calendar function`??

Comment: @Avadhani Y When I export my application,It requires the expire time for my app.like that i'm searching.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using Calendar. You also have two implementation choices:

1- The first time you run the app, save to persistent data the actual date, then every time you execute your app check if the date is before than 10 days of installation, if not, show a message and close your app (or whatever). This approach is not really good, because your user can uninstall your app and install it again so he has 10 more days for using your app.

2- This approach it's a little more "difficult" but I think it's best. The first time you run your app save to your server database a unique ID and date for this device, then, everytime you execute your app, check the actual date with the instalation date on your server.

I hope this may help you as an idea.

Comment: Where I've to store my actual date at first time installation?

Comment: With the first solution in your persistent data, do you use sqlite, shared preferences or something...?
With the second solution, to your web server.

Comment: How to get the current date and store in persistent data during installation?.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is you don't know how to use calendar/time in java and either store persistant data on Android. Here is a hint, take a look and you'll find out it's easier than it seems :)  

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_gettime.htm
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: where I implement the logic.

Answer (score 0):

why not send data, including app and device information, to your server in `OnCreate` when the application runs at the first time. On your server side, you can record the time, and send feedback to client to allow or disallow running.

Comment: So,I've to create web application for client server?.

Comment: just make SOCKET connection I think